# How to make OpenIdConnect multi-tenant?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have an app that uses OpenIdConnect for authorization. Everything works fine. I added Finbuckle.Multitenant to make the app multi-tenant and also set up my custom `TenantInfo`.

One feature that I need is that each tenant might connect to a different authorization server.

Without multi-tenancy, I had the following set up in `Startup.cs`:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = Configuration["Authority"];
    options.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"];
    //etc...
}
```

This worked well originally. However, how can I make it possible that I move the `Authority` per tenant and then connect to that authority when requests come in?

Note:
I'm not using Azure as my IdP.

Comment: With multi-tenancy and an identity provider per tenant set-up, my guess is that you'd simply repeat the calls for AddOpenIdConnect for each authority or have a single identity provider that has the ValidIssuers set to all of the seperate authorities.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following setup, which keeps the software simple and therefore reliable:

- Each running API or web back end has a relationship with a single authorization server (AS), and this must be owned by the same party that builds the software (your company) - this means your code should only ever depend on a single authority
- When users login the AS can manage different authentication methods per partner - as discussed in my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) - in case your requirement is just different authenticators

Multi-tenant data can be managed like this:

- All customers use the same running instances of your software  and when users authenticate you add a Tenant ID claim to access tokens, which can be used during API authorization, to ensure that a user from partner A can never access partner B data
- In the past I have provided software for major banks for which this was not good enough, in which case we spun up extra instances and custom URLs dedicated to that bank. This provided extra assurances of data isolation in case the code was ever wrong - for the dedicated instances only configuration settings needed to change, and the core logic stayed the same - and my company passed on the costs for this level of service.

Note also that all of the above designs are technically simple, and will remain simple as the software grows.

Finally, some AS providers, such as Curity where I work, have support for [multi tenant instances](https://curity.io/resources/learn/curity-multitenancy/), which may give you further design ideas if none of the above works for you.

Comment: Not answering the question whatsoever.